# how to make a reference for settings inside extension contributes/configuration in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

similar to vscode settings reference [image]

am trying to do the same using

```
"someExt.test": {
    "type": "string",
    "default": 'hello',
    "markdownDescription": "test [Emmet](command:workbench.action.openSettings?@ext:vscode.emmet)"
}
```

but it doesn't work & i cant find any documentation for it, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line in the file `resources/app/out/nls.metadata.json` for this option

```
"Controls the delay in ms after which a dirty file is saved automatically.
Only applies when `#files.autoSave#` is set to `{0}`."
```

I don't know if it is documented but

```
`#files.autoSave#`
```

looks like the syntax to get a reference to another setting.

Comment: what exactly is that ?

Comment: @ctf0 looks like the syntax to get a reference to another setting: `\`#files.autoSave#\``

Comment: focken legend, btw do u know a way to also call the extension it self ex.`@ext:vscode.emmet` ?

Comment: @ctf0 have a look at multi-command as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089510/9938317

Comment: cant find anything related to the question https://github.com/ryuta46/vscode-multi-command/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @ctf0 Look at the source code of the extension how they execute the commands

Comment: u mis-understood me, am searching for contributes/configuration, not command execution api

Comment: @ctf0 you can only call the extension by its exported commands

Comment: oh ok, thanx again