# Executing multiple commands at a single key stroke in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

One example of an operation consisting of multiple commands would be the following. I want to copy a line, making a duplicate of it, then, I need to return the the upper line and comment it out. The aim is to reach the following state.

```
previousStatement();
// statementToBeMultipliedAndCommentedOut();
statementToBeMultipliedAndCommentedOut();
nextStatement();
```

Today, I achieve that by a quick combination like this.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>up</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> //commenting out
<kbd>down</kbd>

Is there a way to make a combo executing those keystrokes in a single key binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vscode v1.77 Insiders now (Stable next week) you can run a sequence of commands WITHOUT an extension.  This keybinding would do what you want:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",             // choose your keybinding
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.addCommentLine",
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  }
}
```

For more, see [How can I run multiple commands with a single VS Code keybinding without an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808371/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-with-a-single-vs-code-keybinding-without-an-exte)

---

[Before vscode v1.77]

You need a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) so you can run a sequence of commands.  There are other macro extensions out there.  Using multi-command:

In settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.commentDown",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.addCommentLine",
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  }
]
```

The commands can be found in the Keyboard Shortcuts listing.  Search on SO for "multi-command" to see some of things you can do with it.  (I have no connection to it.)

Choose a keybinding in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.commentDown" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```